# CFML sort Header ASC and DESC (In einer Tabelle sortieren)

Tags: sorting, html-table, cfml

I have a table where I can click the headers to sort the whole table by different columns but only in one way ASC or DESC. How to create a simple header that can do both: sorting ASC and DESC

Here's how it looks like:

```
    <CFIF IsDefined("sort") is "True">
<cfparam name="sort" default="name">
<cfquery name="ad_tabelle" datasource="test">
    SELECT Name, Nachname, Geschlecht, Adresse, Postleitzahl, Land, Datum 
    FROM adresstabelle 
    ORDER BY #sort# 
</cfquery>
<CFELSE>
<CFQUERY name="ad_tabelle" datasource="test">
    SELECT Name, Nachname, Geschlecht, Adresse, Postleitzahl, Land, Datum 
    FROM adresstabelle
</CFQUERY>
</CFIF>

<TABLE border="9" bordercolor="#04B4AE" width="80%" bgcolor=#f0f8ff>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="7"><H3><B>Adressen 

    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=name">Name</A>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=name ASC" class="button">&#8679;</a>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=name DESC" class="button"> &#8681;</a>
        </TD>
        <TD><A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=nachname">Nachname</A>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=nachname ASC" class="button">&#8679;</a>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=nachname DESC" class="button"> &#8681;</a>
        </TD>
        <TD><A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=geschlecht">Geschlecht</A>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=geschlecht ASC" class="button">&#8679;</a>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=geschlecht DESC" class="button"> &#8681;</a>
        </TD>
        <TD><A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=adresse">Adresse</A>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=adresse ASC" class="button">&#8679;</a>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=adresse DESC" class="button"> &#8681;</a>
        </TD>
        <TD><A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=postleitzahl">Postleitzahl</A>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=postleitzahl ASC" class="button">&#8679;</a>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=postleitzahl DESC" class="button"> &#8681;</a>
        </TD>
        <TD><A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=land">Land</A>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=land ASC" class="button">&#8679;</a>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=land DESC" class="button"> &#8681;</a>
        </TD>
        <TD><A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=datum">Datum</A>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=datum ASC" class="button">&#8679;</a>
            <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=datum DESC" class="button"> &#8681;</a>
        </TD>
    </TR>
        <cfoutput query="ad_tabelle">
        <TR>
            <TD><P>#Name#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Nachname#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Geschlecht#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Adresse#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Postleitzahl#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Land#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Datum#</P></TD>

        </TR>
        </cfoutput>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok its done !

```
    <cfparam name="sort" default="name">
<cfquery name="ad_tabelle" datasource="test">
    SELECT Name, Nachname, Geschlecht, Adresse, Postleitzahl, Land, Datum 
    FROM adresstabelle 
    ORDER BY #sort# 
</cfquery>


<TABLE border="9" bordercolor="#04B4AE" width="80%" bgcolor=#f0f8ff>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="7"><H3><B>Adressen 

    <TR>
        <TD>

        <a href="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=name <cfif sort is "name">DESC</cfif>">Name</a>
        </TD>
        <TD>
        <A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=nachname <cfif sort is "nachname">DESC</cfif>">Nachname</A>
        </TD>
        <TD>
        <A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=geschlecht <cfif sort is "geschlecht">DESC</cfif>">Geschlecht</A>
        </TD>
        <TD>
        <A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=adresse <cfif sort is "adresse">DESC</cfif>">Adresse</A>
        </TD>
        <TD>
        <A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=postleitzahl <cfif sort is "postleitzahl">DESC</cfif>">Postleitzahl</A>
        </TD>
        <TD>
        <A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=land <cfif sort is "land">DESC</cfif>">Land</A>
        </TD>
        <TD>
        <A HREF="HalloSeite2.cfm?sort=datum <cfif sort is "datum">DESC</cfif>">Datum</A>
        </TD>
    </TR>
        <cfoutput query="ad_tabelle">
        <TR>
            <TD><P>#Name#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Nachname#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Geschlecht#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Adresse#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Postleitzahl#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Land#</P></TD>
            <TD><P>#Datum#</P></TD>

        </TR>
        </cfoutput>
</table>










<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <Title>Hallo Welt - Seite Zwei </Title>
        </Head>
        <Body>
    <body style="background-color:#00BFFF;">
</body>
```

Comment: While that does work, it makes the query vulnerable to sql injection.  In cases like this, where you cannot use cfqueryparam, validate the parameters first before using them in sql.  For example, `ORDER BY <cfif listFindNoCase("Name,Nachname,....", url.sort)>#url.sort#<cfelse>someDefaultColumnName</cfif>`.  Also, it is a good practice to scope variables ie `url.sort` instead of just `sort`.